# R package sqldf not loading tcltk and returning a warning. How to solve it?

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm using RStudio to run some data analysis and would like to use the package sqldf. Once I require the package, I get the output bellow:

> Loading required package: sqldf
>   Loading required package: gsubfn
>   Loading required package: proto
>   Could not load tcltk.  Will use slower R code instead.
>   Loading required package: RSQLite
>   Warning message:
>   In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>
> > unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
> >     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
> >       Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
> >       Reason: image not found

My sessionInfo() is as follows:

> R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
>   Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
>
> locale:
>   [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] sqldf_0.4-10  RSQLite_1.1-2 gsubfn_0.6-6  proto_1.0.0

Also,

> capabilities()['tcltk']
>   tcltk
>    TRUE

How can I solve this?

Comment: See https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#problem-involvling-tcltk

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you solved the problem but I'll write you the solution that worked for me (found here https://support.bioconductor.org/p/31750/).

You need to go here
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/

and get the tcltk-*.pkg from there.
After installing the package, it won't appear any warnings when you load the sqldf library.